# operator delay in rxjava2

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm new rxjava2.when i read book about it and i have some that i don't understand about operator delay.

> We can postpone emissions using the delay() operator. It will hold any received emissions
>   and delay each one for the specified time period. If we wanted to delay emissions by three
>   seconds, we could do it like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Observable.just("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" ,"Delta",
            "Epsilon")
            .delay(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Received: " + s));

    sleep(3000);
}

public static void sleep(long millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The output of the preceding code snippet is as follows:
 Beta
 Alpha
 Gamma
 Delta
 Epsilon

I think that output is only "Alpha", because they said

> Because delay() operates on a different scheduler (such as Observable.interval()), we
>   need to leverage a sleep() method to keep the application alive long enough to see this
>   happen. Each emission will be delayed by three seconds

with delay 3s, i think there is a emission as "Alpha",but it emit all of emissions in observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be you wanted ?

```
val source1 = Observable.just("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon")

val source2 = Observable.interval(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

val observable = Observable.zip(source1, source2, object : BiFunction<String, Long, Any> {
    override fun apply(t1: String, t2: Long): Any {
        Log.d("Sometag", "Received $t1")
        return "Something"
    }
}).subscribe()
```

Output

```
2019-02-21 13:40:15.502  D/Sometag: Received Alpha
2019-02-21 13:40:18.502  D/Sometag: Received Beta
2019-02-21 13:40:21.502  D/Sometag: Received Gamma
2019-02-21 13:40:24.502  D/Sometag: Received Delta
2019-02-21 13:40:27.502  D/Sometag: Received Epsilon
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html), Delay operator 'delay' emittions within given time.

So, it will display 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta', 'Epsilon', not only 'Alpha'.

```
println("started")

val subscribe = Observable.just("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon")
        .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribe { s -> println("Received: $s") }
```

this code will produce all five strings emitted after 3s.

- 2019-02-21 18:02:30.285 I: started
- 2019-02-21 18:02:33.459 I: Received: Alpha
- 2019-02-21 18:02:33.464 I: Received: Beta
- 2019-02-21 18:02:33.466 I: Received: Gamma
- 2019-02-21 18:02:33.467 I: Received: Delta
- 2019-02-21 18:02:33.469 I: Received: Epsilon

Comment: they said "Each emission will be delayed by three seconds", i think that "Alpha" is delayed 3s as well "Beta"...

Comment: that situation can be acheived with zip operator. just(source).delay only delay first time.

Answer (score 0):

in your case the delay operation will only will delay all stream 3 second and all element will be emitted immediately se more in rx documentation http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html

if you want to delay every element by 3 second you can do it like this :

```
       Observable.fromArray("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta",
            "Epsilon")
            .concatMap(s -> Observable.just(s).delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Received: " + s));
```